# what is the conventional way of providing config information to a custom Powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell

Given that custom PS cmdlets are assemblies I can't provide them config information via the normal App.config route. What is the conventional way of providing config info to a custom cmdlet?

Comment: Reference this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960/powershell-app-config

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell App.Config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960/powershell-app-config)

Comment: Note that PowerShell cmdlets do not have to be assembly based. You can create cmdlets in pure PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Normally i would suggest just using parameters for passing data.

```
Get-MyData -connectionstring $connectionString -table Test ...
```

When that is not practical (too many parameters, etc..), then you can always provide the path to a configuration file by a parameter:

```
Get-MyData -Config .\My.config
```

You can then read the specified configuration file from inside the cmdlet.

This allows users of the cmdlet to define their own configuration files to use.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is a shell.  The normal way of passing information between parts of the shell are shell variables. For powershell that would look like:

```
$global:MyComponent_MySetting = '12'
# i.e. 
$PSDefaultParameterValues
$ErrorActionPreference
```

If settings is expected to be inherited across processes boundaries the convention is to use environment variables.  I extend this to settings that cross C# / PowerShell boundary.  A couple of examples:

```
$env:PATH
$env:PSModulePath
```

If you think this is an anti-pattern for .NET you might want to reconsider.  This is the norm for PAAS hosted apps, and is going to be the new default for ASP.NET running on server-optimized CLR (ASP.NET v5).

See https://github.com/JabbR/JabbRv2/blob/dev/src/JabbR/Startup.cs#L21 
Note: at time of writing I'm linking to `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`

I've revisited this question a few times, including asking it myself.  I wanted to put a stake in the ground to say PowerShell stuff doesn't work well with `<appSettings>`.  IMO it is much better to embrace the shell aspect of PS over the .NET aspect in this regards.

If you need complex configuration take a JSON string.  POSH v3+ has [ConvertFrom-JSON](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849898.aspx) built-in.  If everything in your process uses the same complex configuration put it in a .json file and point to that file from an environment variable.

If a single file doesn't suffice there are well established solutions like the `PATH` pattern, **GIT .gitignore** resolution, or **ASP.NET web.config** resolution (which I won't repeat here).